# How to server a folder of images/css/js in Wai/Warp?

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai, haskell-warp

I have this simple Wai/Warp application

```
app :: Wai.Application
app req respond = respond $ case Wai.rawPathInfo req of
    "/" -> Wai.responseFile status200 [("Content-Type", "text/html")] "views/index.html" Nothing
    _ -> notFound


notFound :: Wai.Response
notFound = Wai.responseLBS status404 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] "404 - Not Found"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    port <- getEnv "PORT"
    let setting = Warp.setPort (read port :: Int) Warp.defaultSettings
    putStrLn $ "start server on the port " ++ port
    Warp.runSettings setting app
```

How can I add a folder "images" to the route so that any image I'll be able to refer to any image from the index.html as "images/something.jpg"? I know how to add an exact route, but here I need to add a whole folder.

Answer (score 1):

[Network.Wai.Middleware.Static](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-middleware-static-0.8.1/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-Static.html#t:Policy) has a `staticPolicy` fn that takes a `Policy` and returns `Middleware` you can add to your Wai app. A `Policy` will define how the URI supplied by the user will be mapped to a filepath. Check out `addBase` for constructing a `Policy`; this may suit your needs just fine.